# ImageView and scrollable TextView using kotlin xml

Tags: android, android-layout

How do i workout with ImageView, TextView(The Title) and Scrollable TextView Content? this is the link i follow, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rz4fgZ2qP0 since it is made in java,

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="202dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="498dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/walking"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titlewindow"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="225dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="368dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="26dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="38dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="401dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-49dp"
        android:text="TextView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my activity

```
class Weight_Loss_DietActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight__loss__diet)
        val content = findViewById(R.id.content) as TextView
        val title = findViewById(R.id.titlewindow) as TextView

        title.setText("WALKING");
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        builder.append(title)
        content.setText("The Content, check the Image")

    }
}
```

this is what its looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textAlignment="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/walking" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTittle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView4"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTittle"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCommentAccept"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="your text..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi, I encountered this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ncf.fitness/com.ncf.fitness.Weight_Loss_DietActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView`

Comment: please check the ids i used different please use same ids  in java class thats are in xml file